# ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'loss/dense_2_loss/Npairloss/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?], [?,10]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, triplet

The error 
`ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'loss/dense_2_loss/Npairloss/MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?], [?,10]`.

```
def Npairloss(y_true,y_pred):
        l2_reg = 0.02
        anchors = y_pred[:,0]    # (n, embedding_size)
        positives = y_pred[:,1]  # (n, embedding_size)
        negatives = y_pred[:2]    # (n, n-1, embedding_size)
        sub_n_p =  negatives - positives
        trans_a= K.transpose(anchors)
        logit = K.dot(trans_a,sub_n_p)  # (n, 1, n-1)
        x = K.sum(K.exp(logit), 2)  # (n, 1)
        loss = K.mean(K.log(1 + x))
        l2_loss = K.sum(anchors ** 2 + positives ** 2) / anchors.shape[0]
        losses = loss + l2_reg * l2_loss
        return losses
```

I am trying to implement the N-pair loss in Keras learning on MNIST. Here the anchor and positive are from the same class, anchor and negative are from different class. 
I dont know whats wrong. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's very hard to say what is wrong without see your y_true and y_pred data. Try to test your loss using tf.Session to print the shapes of each tensor and check if your function is doing what you want.

Comment: the shape of anchor (?,),  shape of  negative  (?, 10), shape of positive  (?,)

Comment: If negative and positive dont have the same shape "sub_n_p =  negatives - positives" will not work.